# What do I put as the password?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

According to a video, I was told to enter my admin password so I just put in my computer password and it was wrong. Pls, help me:)

[image]

Comment: Quite possibly the password has not been set yet, so try leaving it blank, just press the `OK` button. If that works look up how to set the root password. If that does not work, check the install, did you get asked for a password? If you cannot remember the password, search here for `reset root password on MySQL`

Comment: When you installed your mysql database, you should have created a password for the root user. This is the password that it's looking for. If you're on linux, this is not the linux root password, nor is it your personal user's password.  This is the MySQL database's root user's password.